# How to control reindexing that results in high log send queue

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, ola-hallengren

During reindexing using Ola's [IndexOptimize](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html) stored procedure, the log send queues for remote asynchronous replicas can grow quite large if there are a lot of large index defrags, requiring gigantic transaction logs.  There is an @Delay parameter in the script that can be used to insert a delay between each index operation, but it doesn't provide the ability to delay only when the log send queues are high.

A more intelligent throttling mechanism is required to control the log send queue sizes during heavy reindexing.

And yes, I know that reindexing isn't really necessary with our enterprise SSDs, but we do it to appease the third-party support organizations that will blame fragmentation for any performance issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert the following code into the IndexOptimize procedure to implement a wait that will allow the log send queues to flush before continuing.  As written it will continue once there is less than 1 GB in the log send queues.

```
/* Pause until the log send queue is less than 1 GB */ 
WHILE ( (SELECT Sum(log_send_queue_size) 
         FROM   sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states 
         WHERE  is_local = 0) > 1000000 ) 
  BEGIN 
      WAITFOR delay '00:01:00' 
  END
```

This code needs to be placed immediately after the `IF @Delay > 0` block in the procedure.  With the current version of IndexOptimize, it would look like this:

```
IF @Delay > 0
BEGIN
    SET @CurrentDelay = DATEADD(ss,@Delay,'1900-01-01')
    WAITFOR DELAY @CurrentDelay
END

/* Pause until the log send queue is less than 1 GB */ 
WHILE ( (SELECT Sum(log_send_queue_size) 
         FROM   sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states 
         WHERE  is_local = 0) > 1000000 ) 
  BEGIN 
      WAITFOR delay '00:01:00' 
  END
```